# ASP.NET Core: How to connect route parameter with query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I have route with connected action which retrieves blog post drom database and displays it.

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetPostToShow",
    template: "posts/{postId:int}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPostToShow" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodRouteConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) });
```

Which results in url

```
https://localhost:44300/posts/2002
```

But I want it to look like this

```
https://localhost:44300/posts?postId=2002
```

So how I can implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?postId=2002 is a GET variable and can be gotten as an argument in the controller method.

So you wouild simplify your MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "GetPostToShow",
template: "posts",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPostToShow" },
constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodRouteConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) });
```

And in the Controller have the Method:

```
public IActionResult GetPostToShow(int postId)
```

Of course even nicer is to use the decorator routing in my opinion. Then you would remove the MapRoute call and instead add the following decorator to the method:

```
[HttpGet("posts")]
public IActionResult GetPostToShow(int postId)
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but it was just preambula for another question. Unfortunately StackOverflow gives ability to post one question in 90 minutes. So stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes look like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "GetPostToShow",
template: "posts/{postId(0)}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPostToShow" },
constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodRouteConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) });
```

Your GetPostToShow method in controller side look like below.

```
public virtual IActionResult GetPostToShow (int postId) 
{
    // your code and return view
}
```

Or into CSHTML page you want to use like below code.

`@Url.RouteUrl("posts", new {postId= yourpostsIdhere})`